# System Null Reference error when retrieving data from database

Tags: vb.net

I'm getting a system null reference error on this code. It searches for a random filename which may or may not exist. It works fine if a filename exists. If none exist then I get this error, it doesn't seem to want to do the 'ELSE' part where I assign filename="no results"

VB.Net...

```
Public Function GetFeaturedItem(ByVal accountID As Guid) As String

    Dim DBConnect55 As New DBConn
    Dim filename As String
    Using db As DbConnection = DBConnect55.Conn("DBConnectionString")
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = DBConnect55.Command(db, "SelectFeaturedItem")
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("accountID", SqlDbType.Uniqueidentifier, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = accountID

        db.Open()
        Dim DR As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        While DR.Read
            If NOT IsDbNull(DR("filename")) Then
                filename = DR("filename")
            Else
                filename="no results"
            End If
        End While
        DR.Close()
        DR = Nothing
        cmd.Dispose()
        cmd = Nothing
        db.Dispose()
        db.Close()
    End Using
    Return filename
End Function
```

SQL...

```
SELECT TOP 1 filename FROM tblItems WHERE accountID=@accountID AND valid='1'
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

I CALL IT LIKE THIS..

```
featuredItem(noOfResults) = getFeaturedItem(DR("accountID")).ToString
```

Comment: 1) If you need only one value from database, then use [ExecuteScalar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar) method. 2) There's no need to call `ToString` in `getFeaturedItem(DR("accountID")).ToString` since you *already* have a string. 3) Which line throws error?

Comment: Thank you. I took the .ToString off when I call the function and it works perfectly now. I will mark this as the answer when it allows me to do so.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this in the debugger?  Have you considered what happens if `DR.Read` returns `False` on the first time through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `ToString` in `getFeaturedItem(DR("accountID")).ToString`.